# Windows service Signalr authentication expires

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, signals

I have a Windows Services which connects to a Signalr Hub. 
The Service receives barcode scans and sends the barcode to the Hub.
Users request en webpage which uses jTable to show the scanned barcodes in a grid. 
The webapplication uses winforms authentication with sliding expiration.
This works fine till some point in time the authentication cookie becomes invalid. How can i detect if an authentication cookie becomes invalid?

At startup off the service I create a hub connection.

```
private static IHubProxy _bufferProxy;
private static HubConnection _hubConnection;



protected static async void InitBufferHub()
    {
        bool connected = false;
        while(!connected)
        {

            try
            {
                _hubConnection = new HubConnection(Settings.Default.HubConnection);
                Cookie returnedCookie;
                 var authResult = AuthenticateUser("user", "password", out returnedCookie);

                if (authResult)
                {
                    _hubConnection.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                    _hubConnection.CookieContainer.Add(returnedCookie);
                    Log.Debug("User logged in");
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Debug("Login failed");
                }

                _bufferProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("buffer");

                await _hubConnection.Start();

                connected = true;
                Log.Debug("Hub proxy created");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("OnStart", ex);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

        }
    }

    internal static async void SendBufferItem(BufferItem bufferItem)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_hubConnection.State == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
            {
                _bufferProxy = null;
                _hubConnection.Dispose();
                InitBufferHub();
            }

            await _bufferProxy.Invoke("RecordCreated", bufferItem);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("SendBufferItem error: ", ex);
        }

    }
```